# ORA-00905: missing keyword error oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi when i am trying to execute following `oracle` query I am getting

> [Err] ORA-00905: missing keyword

```
CREATE VIEW MJNSXJJRW_view AS  
SELECT B.oID AS "_oid", B.oTm AS "_otm" 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT oID, oTm FROM MJNSXJJRW) B 
LEFT JOIN MJNSXJJRW AS S0 ON 
    B.oID = S0.oID AND 
    S0.idx = 0 AND 
    S0.kID = "str_val" ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely issue is `MJNSXJJRW AS S0`. You use the `AS` keyword when defining column aliases, not when defining table aliases.

```
CREATE VIEW MJNSXJJRW_view AS  
SELECT B.oID AS "_oid", B.oTm AS "_otm" 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT oID, oTm FROM MJNSXJJRW) B 
LEFT JOIN MJNSXJJRW S0 ON 
    B.oID = S0.oID AND 
    S0.idx = 0 AND 
    S0.kID = "str_val" ;
```

I'm assuming that `"str_val"` is a column, not a string literal. If it's the latter you should use single quotes.

Comment: thanks alan, it really helped me to resolve this issue.